# Collection of promises issue

Tags: jquery, promise

What is the syntax for writing a series of promises into a series of animations that can be collected at the end? I've read the jquery manual, viewed a couple of relevant SO questions but i can't seem to get the .done() message to fire after all animations complete.

Code so far:

```
 $.when(

    $graphName.fadeIn(500).promise().then(function(){
        $graphaxes.each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(700).promise().then(function(){
                $(".circle.bk").each(function(index) {
                    $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(700).promise().then( function(){
                        $graphlabel.each(function(index) {
                            $(this).delay(600).fadeIn(800).promise().then( function(){
                                fadeLabels();
                                $(".circle").each(function(index) {
                                    $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(700).promise();                                         


                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    })  

    ).done(function(){
        console.log("All animations complete");
    });
```

Comment: You deleted and then undeleted this, would you like an answer or are you going to delete it again?

Comment: I would like an answer or a point in the right direction please! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises *chain*, you don't have to and frankly *shouldn't* nest them. This is the biggest source of strength in them. You can return from promises and then chain to them, that `.then` will execute once the inner promises you supplied fulfills.

```
$graphName.fadeIn(500).promise().then(function(){
    // map each item to a promise, wait for all, if you don't want to wait remove
    // the $.when.apply around it and return a $.when on the single value
    return $.when.apply(null, $graphaxes.map(function(i, gi) { 
        return $(gi).delay(500 * i).fadeIn(700).promise();
    }).get()); // to get an array
}).then(function(res){
    // now animate all the circles, again if you don't want to wait remove
    // the $.when.apply so it won't wait
    return $.when.apply(null, $(".circle.bk").map(function(i, el) {
        return $(this).delay(500 * i).fadeIn(700).promise()
    }));
}).then(function(res){
     return $.when.apply(null, $graphlabel.map(function(i, el) {
          return $(el).delay(600).fadeIn(800).promise()
     }).get());
}).then(function(res){
    fadeLabels(); // this calls fadeLabels() once, if you want to call it for 
                  // each promise you can of course do it
    return $.when.apply(null, $(".circle").map(function(index) {
          return $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(700).promise();                                         
    }).get());
}).then(function(res){
    console.log("All animations complete");
});
```

Comment: Nice one, much appreciated. I nearly had it in a demo upon re-writing it and had read about apply for arrays, it was the .map and .get that got me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it a bit simpler than your accepted answer because jQuery will return a promise that represents the entire collection so you don't have to use `$.when()` to manage that yourself.  This is one of the really nice features of the `.promise()` method called on a collection that is all animating.  So, I think you can do this:

```
$graphName.fadeIn(500).promise().then(function(){
    return graphaxes.each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(500 * i).fadeIn(700);
    }).promise();
}).then(function() {
    return $(".circle.bk").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(700);
    }).promise();
}).then(function() {
    return $graphlabel.delay(600).fadeIn(800).promise();
}).then(function() {
    fadeLabels();
    return $(".circle").each(function(index) {
         $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(700);
    }).promise();
}).then(function() {
    console.log("all animations complete");
});
```

---

And, if you create one jQuery plug-in method for your progressive delays, you can simplify the code even more to this:

```
jQuery.fn.fadeInProgressive = function(delayFactor, fadeTime) {
    return this.each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(delayFactor * index).fadeIn(fadeTime);
    });
};

$graphName.fadeIn(500).promise().then(function(){
    return graphaxes.fadeInProgressive(500, 700).promise();
}).then(function() {
    return $(".circle.bk").fadeInProgressive(500, 700).promise();
}).then(function() {
    return $graphlabel.delay(600).fadeIn(800).promise();
}).then(function() {
    fadeLabels();
    return $(".circle").fadeInProgressive(500, 700).promise();
}).then(function() {
    console.log("all animations complete");
});
```

Comment: @lxm7 - I thought you might like to see an even simpler way to use the jQuery `.promise()` method in this answer.

Comment: Yes, muuuuuch cleaner.

Comment: There's probably a (very small) performance advantage in returning `.last().promise()` in each case. This will give the jQuery internals less work to do, and should work because (due to the nature of the desired fadeIn progressions) the last element in each collection will be the last to complete.