# fade in children sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay, fadein

I am trying to have each element of the list fade in sequentially. I know there have been many similar questions asked, but I can't seem to find out whats wrong! Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('li.menu-item-type-custom').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings().find('ul.sub-menu').hide();
        $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(300*(index)).fadeTo(1000,1); 
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT:
It is not coming in sequentially.
Here is the DOM I am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/m0vxjqsj/2/

Comment: what problems you are facing from running this code? it is not fading a all? or not fading sequentially. it should work as you have given delay()

Comment: This [**very related question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931689/collection-of-promises-issue) should give you the idea. In short - chain promises.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine.... http://jsfiddle.net/m0vxjqsj/ ... perhaps you should show the dom you are working with? or explain what you want to happen compared to what is happening...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, the question you linked to seems to be more for when you have a static amount of different and specific things that you need to happen. In this case, that would be a lot of unnecessary code and would not work if the number of children is dynamic. The way he is doing it seems to work when I try it (see fiddle above)... could also be done with a recursive callback.

Comment: Hey guys, made an edit. I included the DOM in the fiddle link. I also noted that the problem is that it isn't loading in sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to fade in the sub menus when it appears you want to fade in the `li`'s within the sub menus... I added `.children()` before the `.hide()` and before the `.each()`...

I believe this is what you want...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ca2r5nvd/1/)

```
$('li.menu-item-type-custom').click(function () {

    $(this).siblings().find('ul.sub-menu').children().hide();

    $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').children().each(function (index) {
        $(this).delay(300 * (index)).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    });
});
```